# body-transformer plugin not available in APISIX 3.4.1 version

Tags: plugins, apache-apisix

We have APISIX version 3.4.1 installed and Dashboard version 3.0 using docker.

we want to enable body-transformer plugin.
when we go to plugin option on dashboard and see the list. body-transformer plug in is not available.

we tried by adding to body-transformer into plugin list of apisix config.yml and restarted the docker container.
but still we can't see the plugin on dashboard.

please help us how to get body-transformer plugin option in to APISIX dashboard

Comment: Finally we could resolve this by following steps as per below

https://github.com/apache/apisix-docker/issues/443